# Awesome WM buggy rc.lua

Tags: awesome

I'm new to awesome, and I'm having trouble configuring a theme from the following repository: [here](https://github.com/mikar/awesome-themes)

I just moved the themes to my awesome directory, so the tree looks like this:

```
~/.config/awesome/
-- rc.lua
-- themes
   -- anon
   -- multicolor # these are the themes from github
# etc
```

The `rc.lua` is copied from one of the themes here are its contents:

```
--[[

     Steamburn Awesome WM config 2.0 
     github.com/copycat-killer       

--]]

local awful = require("awful")
awful.util = require("awful.util")

--{{{ Main
theme = {}

home          = os.getenv("HOME")
config        = awful.util.getdir("config")
shared        = "/usr/share/awesome"
if not awful.util.file_readable(shared .. "/icons/awesome16.png") then
    shared    = "/usr/share/local/awesome"
end
sharedicons   = shared .. "/icons"
sharedthemes  = shared .. "/themes"
themes        = config .. "/themes"
themename     = "/steamburn"
if not awful.util.file_readable(themes .. themename .. "/theme.lua") then
       themes = sharedthemes
end
themedir      = themes .. themename

wallpaper1    = themedir .. "/wall.png"
wallpaper2    = themedir .. "/background.png"
wallpaper3    = sharedthemes .. "/zenburn/zenburn-background.png"
wallpaper4    = sharedthemes .. "/default/background.png"
wpscript      = home .. "/.wallpaper"

if awful.util.file_readable(wallpaper1) then
  theme.wallpaper = wallpaper1
elseif awful.util.file_readable(wallpaper2) then
  theme.wallpaper = wallpaper2
elseif awful.util.file_readable(wpscript) then
  theme.wallpaper_cmd = { "sh " .. wpscript }
elseif awful.util.file_readable(wallpaper3) then
  theme.wallpaper = wallpaper3
else
  theme.wallpaper = wallpaper4
end
--}}}

theme.font                          = "Tamsyn 10.5"
theme.fg_normal                     = "#cdcdcd"
theme.fg_focus                      = "#d79d38"
theme.fg_urgent                     = "#CC9393"
theme.bg_normal                     = "#140c0b"
theme.bg_focus                      = "#140c0b"
theme.bg_urgent                     = "#2a1f1e"
theme.border_width                  = "1"
theme.border_normal                 = "#140c0f"
theme.border_focus                  = "#915543"
theme.border_marked                 = "#CC9393"
theme.taglist_fg_focus              = "#d47456"
theme.tasklist_bg_focus             = "#140c0b"
theme.tasklist_fg_focus             = "#d47456"
theme.menu_height                   = "16"
theme.menu_width                    = "140"

theme.layout_txt_tile               = "[t]"
theme.layout_txt_tileleft           = "[l]"
theme.layout_txt_tilebottom         = "[b]"
theme.layout_txt_tiletop            = "[tt]"
theme.layout_txt_fairv              = "[fv]"
theme.layout_txt_fairh              = "[fh]"
theme.layout_txt_spiral             = "[s]"
theme.layout_txt_dwindle            = "[d]"
theme.layout_txt_max                = "[m]"
theme.layout_txt_fullscreen         = "[F]"
theme.layout_txt_magnifier          = "[M]"
theme.layout_txt_floating           = "[|]"

theme.menu_submenu_icon             = themedir .. "/icons/submenu.png"
theme.taglist_squares_sel           = themedir .. "/icons/square_sel.png"
theme.taglist_squares_unsel         = themedir .. "/icons/square_unsel.png"

theme.tasklist_disable_icon         = true
theme.tasklist_floating             = ""
theme.tasklist_maximized_horizontal = ""
theme.tasklist_maximized_vertical   = ""

return theme
```

It is not working, it just displays the cursor on a black screen whit no background not taskbar and you can't open terminals or anything else.

Also I copied the themes to `/usr/share/awesome/themes` but I don't think it is the problem.

I'm on arch-linux my version of awesome is `3.5.2`.

If some one has done this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your configuration with [`awesome --check`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/3343ac5ea305a7a67186457c30a552144563aaaf/.bash_history#L31). That should at least give you an idea of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `.xinitrc` you can [enable logging to file](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/FAQ#Where_are_logs.2C_error_messages_or_something.3F):

```
exec /usr/bin/awesome >> ~/.cache/awesome/stdout 2>> ~/.cache/awesome/stderr
```